# MongoDB Aggregate - Count objects of a specific matching field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to know how to use aggregate() to take all of the objects of a specific field (i.e. "user") and count them.

This what I am doing:

I want to return a list of users with the sum of how many tweets that have made?

So I want output that looks like

Etc..

Also I don't want repeating users like

Etc..

which is what the above aggregate does.

So basically, how can I modify this aggregate to ensure the objects are unique?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will want to group by the user.id field instead of the user object. You can try doing that directly

```
$group: {_id: "$user.id", totalTweets: {$sum: 1} }
```

Or you might want to try projecting that field onto the document before grouping

```
$addFields: {userId: "$user.id"}
$group: {_id: "$userId", totalTweets: {$sum: 1} }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want whole inner **user** object in each documents after aggregation then you have to use `$push` operator in aggregation
and also you need to do the aggregation on unique id of users e.g: `id` or `id_str` instead of `$user` object as in your question.

```
db.tweets.aggregate([{ $group: {_id: "$user.id", totalTweets: { $sum: 1 }, user : { $push: "$user" }  }    }])
```

This will solved your problem. For details about `$push` operator, have a look at official documents [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push)